# SwiftUI ForEach not working after recent update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui

I've been using ForEach for a while now, it has been working fine until I updated my Xcode a couple days ago, now it says "Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred". Anyone else experiences the same issue?

```
ForEach(dataArray) { data in
...
}
```

Comment: What is type of data? Can you show declaration?

Comment: Try `ForEach(dataArray, id: \.self)` instead of `ForEach(dataArray)`, or conform the type of `dataArray` elements to `Identifiable`.

Answer (score 7):

Anytime you get that error, you should just use the following overload of ForEach:

```
ForEach(0..<dataArray.count, id: \.self) { index in 
   //refer to your items as dataArray[index] inside ForEach
}
```

You get the error because your `dataArray` elements are not conforming to `Identifiable` protocol.